# Adding a new column in R data frame based on time intervals. Day/Night

Tags: r

I want to add a new column to my dataframe based on a time interval.
For the time 10:00 - 15:00 I want to add "day" in the new column, for 22:00-03:00 I want to add "night". Additionally I want to exclude all rows which aren't in one of the intervals

I've used as.POSIXct already.

This is what I want:

```
hour    D_N
10:31   day
01:10   night
12:03   day
14:51   day
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lubridate` and `dplyr` package. Convert the column to `Period` class and extract the `hour` from it. Assign `"day"` and `"night"` according to `hour` of the day and remove rows which do not lie in one of those intervals.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(hour = hour(hm(hour1)), 
         D_N = case_when(hour %in% 10:15 ~ "day", 
                         hour %in% 22:23 | hour %in% 1:3 ~ "night", 
                         TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(D_N))

#  hour1 hour   D_N
#1 10:31   10   day
#2 01:10    1 night
#3 12:03   12   day
#4 14:51   14   day
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(hour1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("01:10", 
"10:31", "12:03", "14:51", "16:03"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Your code is not working somehow. Could you check out my answer

Comment: @emelyann It does work. Try `df %>%
  mutate(hour = hour(hm(time)), 
         D_N = case_when(hour %in% 10:14 ~ "day", 
                         hour %in% 22:23 | hour %in% 1:3 ~ "night", 
                         TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(D_N))` , what does it give to you ? Also if you want to add data to your post edit your question instead of adding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my data frame. 
I tried your code, but it doesn't exclude the times I dont want to have: 15:00-22:00 and 03:00-10:00

```
          date  time           date_time
1   2017-05-25 10:16 2017-05-25 10:16:00
2   2017-05-27 13:16 2017-05-27 13:16:00
3   2017-05-28 05:31 2017-05-28 05:31:00
4   2017-05-28 08:01 2017-05-28 08:01:00
5   2017-05-29 14:31 2017-05-29 14:31:00
6   2017-05-30 09:01 2017-05-30 09:01:00
7   2017-05-31 03:31 2017-05-31 03:31:00
8   2017-05-31 07:16 2017-05-31 07:16:00
9   2017-06-03 06:01 2017-06-03 06:01:00
10  2017-06-03 10:16 2017-06-03 10:16:00
11  2017-06-03 14:01 2017-06-03 14:01:00
12  2017-06-04 05:31 2017-06-04 05:31:00
13  2017-06-04 12:16 2017-06-04 12:16:00
14  2017-06-04 15:16 2017-06-04 15:16:00
15  2017-06-05 03:31 2017-06-05 03:31:00
```

so what I want is:

```
          date  time           date_time  D_N
1   2017-05-25 10:16 2017-05-25 10:16:00   day
2   2017-05-27 13:16 2017-05-27 13:16:00   day
3   2017-05-28 05:31 2017-05-28 05:31:00       #should be excluded
4   2017-05-28 08:01 2017-05-28 08:01:00       #should be excluded
5   2017-05-29 14:31 2017-05-29 14:31:00   day
6   2017-05-30 09:01 2017-05-30 09:01:00       #should be excluded
7   2017-05-31 03:31 2017-05-31 03:31:00 night
8   2017-05-31 07:16 2017-05-31 07:16:00       #should be excluded
9   2017-06-03 06:01 2017-06-03 06:01:00       #should be excluded
10  2017-06-03 10:16 2017-06-03 10:16:00   day
11  2017-06-03 14:01 2017-06-03 14:01:00   day
12  2017-06-04 05:31 2017-06-04 05:31:00       #should be excluded
13  2017-06-04 12:16 2017-06-04 12:16:00   day
14  2017-06-04 15:16 2017-06-04 15:16:00       #should be excluded
15  2017-06-05 03:31 2017-06-05 03:31:00 night
as a result I want:
```

to get this:

```
          date  time           date_time  D_N
1   2017-05-25 10:16 2017-05-25 10:16:00   day
2   2017-05-27 13:16 2017-05-27 13:16:00   day
5   2017-05-29 14:31 2017-05-29 14:31:00   day
7   2017-05-31 03:31 2017-05-31 03:31:00 night
10  2017-06-03 10:16 2017-06-03 10:16:00   day
11  2017-06-03 14:01 2017-06-03 14:01:00   day
13  2017-06-04 12:16 2017-06-04 12:16:00   day
15  2017-06-05 03:31 2017-06-05 03:31:00 night
```